# 12 students into groups of 2. Why doesn't my solution work?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem:
There are 12 students in the class. How many ways are there to split them into working groups of size 2 to work on the same assignment?
I know the solution but I don't understand why my solution doesn't work.
My solution is:
Let's choose the first members of each group, it's combination ${12 \choose{} 6}=924$ (we have no order and no repetitions, n = 12 = number of students, k = 6 = number of groups). Then, let's choose the second members of each group, it's permutation $\frac{6!}{(6-6)!}=720$ (now order matters because we already have first members and still no repetitions, n = 6 = number of remaining students, k = 6 = number of groups). Also, we need to divide the result by 2 to account that the order inside a group doesn't matter ({1, 3} = {3, 1}). So it's $924*720/2=332640$

Comment: The same six groups of students can be achieved by many different choices of “first” students: eg if the groups are $(1,2)$, $(3,4)$, etc, then $1,3,5,7,9,11$ works, but $1,4,5,7,9,11$ too and $1,3,6,8,10,11$ and many others!

Comment: @Mindlack thanks! Got it

Comment: @Mindlack but doesn't the final division by 2 account for this overcounting?

Comment: @Mindlack at least for these cases you demonstrated

Comment: no, since there are more (far more!) than two choices of “first students” that lead to the same set of pairs!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution does work, you just made a mistake at the end. ({1,2},{3,4},...), ({1,2},{4,3},...), ({2,1},{3,4},...) and so on are all equivalent, but counted separately by 924*720. Since each group of two can either be flipped or not flipped, there are $2^6$ ways to do this type of rearrangement, and the answer is $\frac{924*720}{2^6}=10395$. This agrees with user2661923’s answer, which uses a more common method.

Comment: +1 nice picking up the slack.

Answer (score 0):

You want to enumerate the number of ways of forming $6$ distinct pairs.

That is
$$\frac{(12)!}{(2!)^6} = \binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}.$$

**However** the above computation overlooks overcounting, re in any specific partion into 6 pairs, there are $(6!)$ ways of **ordering** when each pair is created.

So, you have to multiply the above enumeration by the *overcounting scalar* of $\frac{1}{(6)!}.$

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Although I already know this solution. I'm rather interested in why my solution doesn't work

Comment: @paisleygreenwood Examine the comment of Mindlack, immediately following your query.  Good point, that protocol is to discuss flaws in the query before giving answer, but Mindlack's comment already did that.